# Serial protocol comunication

Tags: serial-port

I am having first contact with serial communication, I have to communicate through java with a serial device that came with a manual communication protocol, I wanted you guys help me understand only the part that matters : the command part

```
FORMAT : <command><size><data><checksum>
<command> : 1 byte type : CAPITAL LETTER from 'A' to 'Z'
<size> : 1 byte type : char between 0 and 255
<data> : String composed of <size> bytes : Format is depending on the command
<checksum> Calculated as follow : checksum = -(<command> + <size> + [b]E[/b](<data>(i))) modulo 0x100   ([b]E[/b] sum simbol)

Command example : 0x43,0x10,0x87,0x31,0x2E,0x35 (What this means in string format?)

CheckSum calculation : 
  0x43+0x10+0x87+0x31+0x2E+0x35 = 0x16E (How to sum this ?)
  Then calcule it complement : -0x16E = 0xE92
  Then : checksum = 0xE92 modulo 0x100 = 0x92
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my handy ASCII table 0x43 is 'C'.
Size is 0x10 = 16
Data is 0x87 ...

> 0x43+0x10+0x87+0x31+0x2E+0x35 = 0x16E (How to sum this ?)

Just add them with '+'

Complement is '~'

Masking to just a byte is '& 0xff' which you don't need to do if you keep all of your arithmetic in bytes.

Comment: About 'C' command document says : 

Command : <'C',0x10,calibrationtype,"xx.xx","xx.xx","xxxx",CheckSum>
                                     Coval , CO2val , Hcval

Calibrationtype : 

b7 : 1 point (used ih the field) calibration if set to 1
b6 : 3 points calibration : low point 1 if set to 1
b5 : 3 points calibration : middle point 2 if set to 1 
.
.
.

do you know what means "0x87" ? Because "0x31,0x2E,0x35" seams to be 1.5

C16'0x87'1.5'checksum'